# Create a Linq Expression with StartsWith, EndsWith and Contains passing a Expression<Func<T, string>>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a method passing a expression of type `Expression<Func<T, string>` to create expression of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` to filter a string property with the `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `Contains` methods like these expressions:

```
.Where(e => e.MiProperty.ToUpper().StartsWith("ABC"));
.Where(e => e.MiProperty.ToUpper().EndsWith("XYZ"));
.Where(e => e.MiProperty.ToUpper().Contains("MNO"));
```

the method should look like:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddFilterToStringProperty<T>(Expresssion<Func<T, string>> pMyExpression, string pFilter, FilterType pFiltertype)
```

where FilterType is an enum type that contains the three of the mentioned operations (`StartsWith`, `EndsWith`, `Contains`)

Comment: Go for it. Let us know what you try, and if it doesn't work, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddFilterToStringProperty<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, string>> expression, string filter, FilterType type)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            expression.Body,
            type.ToString(),
            null,
            Expression.Constant(filter)),
        expression.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: I have added a "not null" expression to this answer

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @dtb. It works fine and I added a "not null" expression for this case like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddFilterToStringProperty2<T>(
                        Expression<Func<T, string>> expression, string filter, FilterType type)
    {
        var vNotNullExpresion = Expression.NotEqual(
                                expression.Body,
                                Expression.Constant(null));

        var vMethodExpresion = Expression.Call(
                expression.Body,
                type.ToString(),
                null,
                Expression.Constant(filter));

        var vFilterExpresion = Expression.AndAlso(vNotNullExpresion, vMethodExpresion);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            vFilterExpresion,
            expression.Parameters);
    }
```